# How to integrate role and permissions through LDAP in a Java based web application

Tags: jsp, servlets, ldap, integration, roles

I'm attempting to get roles and permissions from an LDAP server and show some part of web application for authorized users only. 
Users have been successfully authenticated through LDAP using JNDI APIS in JSP. But now I'm struggling to find how to configure roles and permissions with the LDAP server to determine web application access and then read those roles and permissions in JSP using JNDI.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any in built Roles / Permissions in any standard LDAP server. There are two ways to do it

1. Create an OU=Roles , create Groups under it , consider Groups as roles , add users to these groups as uniqueMembers
2. You need to define your schema for Roles. Define an ObjectClass indicating role, create entries/roles with this ObjectClass as the type.

Change the User/Group schema to have a custom entry to contain the above created roles.

Comment: Thanks this helps with roles creation, how to go with permissions?

Comment: Well I think you can follow the JAAS model : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/a97690/jaas_int.htm